# How to get MacBook Air screen to turn off

Tags: sleep-wake, screen-lock

I have my MacBook Air screen configured to turn off after a few minutes of inactivity (the same configuration I've had for many years and a couple of hardware upgrades) but now, suddenly, it will not turn off. The screen saver (just an image, also unchanged for years) will engage on schedule, but the screen never turns off.

What could be causing this? How do I get the old behavior back?

---

*CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_blizzard_avalanche; macOS: 13.5-arm64*

Comment: I'm running an M2 MBA with 13.5 and I cannot replicate this. Can you boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) and see if the problem still persists.  This will help rule out 3rd party apps/drivers.

Comment: Report back what you found after booting into Safe Mode. If the problem still persists in Safe Mode, then also try creating a new user account and logging into that to test what the MBA does with the same settings.

Comment: It was an rogue app: [Paku](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paku-for-purpleair/id1534130193).